# How to define a client/server relationship between two players. Real time matches

Tags: ios, real-time, game-center

we are working on a game with real-time matches. 2 players. 1 against 1.
I have to define a list of items in common between the 2 players before the game start.

It's not really a problem in the case of 1 player invite another. In this case i can define the player receiving the invite as the "client". The app of the "server" player will generate the list.

But in the case of an "auto-match" not sure how i can define this kind of relationship between my players as the same code is going to run the same way on the two instance of the apps.

Edit:
Will try this idea:
Will use a timeelapsed between beginning of the connection and the accepted connection. Exchange the data between users and determine which one should be consider as master/server.

Will post a detail example if the implementation working.
Meanwhile, still opened to any others suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In peer-peer networking, each device can function as the server. Make your networking client/server agnostic once the connection is made so that it doesn't matter.

I had that same problem and ended up defining my own network classes on top of AsyncSocket so that I could communicate in a middle layer. It's here if you're interested:

[github link here](https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABNetConnection)

It suited my needs and it may give you some ideas.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I am using GameKit so all the network parts is handled by the framework. My problem was more on a logic/functionnal level to determine during the game configuration period how to define a client/server master/slave relationship between the players.